# What are the big battles that took place in Hindu mythology

Tags: gods, asuras, war

Like I know - Ramayana, Mahabharata, Battle of the 10 Kings and the war between Indra and the king of Asuras (Vitmitra).

But there are many other battles and wars that took place which are slightly mentioned at places but their whole story is never given out fully.

What are the other wars between Devas and Asuras. Or a war where Devas and Asuras have to unite to beat somebody.

Comment: Welcome @shreyansh soni to Stack exchange. ;)
There are almost a lot of fights and i don't think except samudra manthana devas and asuras have worked togethet. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The fight between brihaspati and chandra**

> The Moon and the Lunar Dynasty
>   There was a sage named Atri. Atri performed
>   very difficult tapasya. So difficult was the
>   tapasya that Atri’s energy was thrown up into
>   the sky. The sky could not bear the energy
>   and hurled it down onto the earth. This
>   energy then gave birth to Soma or Chandra,
>   the moon god. Brahma took Chandra up into
>   his chariot and drove the chariot around the
>   earth twenty-one times. From whatever
>   energy was left after Chandra had been
>   created, the herbs were born.
>   Chandra also performed very difficult
>   tapasya. One padma year consists of
>   10,000,000,000,000 normal years. For one
>   hundred such padma years, Chandra
>   meditated. After the meditation was over,
>   Brahma appointed Chandra lord over seeds,
>   herbs, brahmanas and the oceans. Chandra
>   also performed a rajasuya yajna (royal
>   sacrifice) as a celebration of his lordship.
>   This gave him a lot of pomp, glory, wealth
>   and respect.
>   But all this merely served to turn Chandra’s
>   head. The guru (teacher) of the gods was the
>   sage Brihaspati. Brihaspati had a wife named
>   Tara and Chandra abducted Tara. Despite the
>   gods and the sages asking Chandra to return
>   Tara., the moon god would not listen. A
>   terrible war then raged over Tara, the gods
>   fighting for Brihaspati and the demons
>   fighting for Chandra. Shukracharya, the guru
>   of the demons, fought with Chandra and
>   Shiva fought with Brihaspati. This war
>   (samgrama) came to be known as
>   tarakamaya samgrama, since it was fought
>   over Tara.
>   Finally Brahma intervened and a truce was
>   called. But Chandra and Tara had by then
>   had a son, and Brihaspati refused to accept
>   this son as his own. This son was Budha. As
>   you already know, Budha married Ila and
>   they had a son named Pururava.

—bramha purana(http://www.bharatadesam.com/spiritual/brahma_purana.php )

Andhaka and lord shiva — http://www.bharatadesam.com/spiritual/shiva_purana.php

Banasur annd krishna— https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banasura

fight between vaali and raavana— [How did Vali defeat Ravana? What's the story?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7472/how-did-vali-defeat-ravana-whats-the-story)

Parashurama and  Kartavirya Arjuna:— https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kartavirya_Arjuna

Ravana and Kartavirya Arjuna:— https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kartavirya_Arjuna

Shiva and jalandhara:— https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jalandhara

Comment: Any better source than Wikipedia? Adding just links make it a link like answer.